# Need HELP about Event Calendar in ASP.NET VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Do you know some event calendar just likes this?[image]

I just saw this simple month calendar here.
http://www.microsoft.com/events/webcasts/calendar/monthview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use one in a project?

You can use a regular ASP:Calendar control. Set the control's day width and height like so:

```
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"  >
        <DayStyle Height="100" Width="125" />
    </asp:Calendar>
```

Which will give you the "calendar blocks" look you want.

The DayRender event will allow you to add items to individual days:

```
Protected Sub Calendar1_DayRender(ByVal sender As Object, _ ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs) _ Handles Calendar1.DayRender
End Sub
```

Access the DayRenders e.Day.Date object to get the day that is being rendered, this is a regular datetime.